# will the chrome stable channel have panels enabled by default soon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

They are currently enabled by default in canary and dev channels ... so maybe it will be enabled by default in the beta and stable channels over time? Thank you very much!

Or is this something that is not possible to predict?

Google says that features in the canary and dev channels generally move to the beta and stable channels as do third party sources.

For example:http://browserfame.com/297/chrome-panel-enabled-chrome-17

"This means that the panel feature is coming soon to the regular stable version of Chrome."

However panels have been enabled by default in canary and dev but not in beta or stable since 2011 ...

Comment: True, maybe this is not possible to predict, I added an edit to reflect that. I thought maybe the process was reasonably predictable because of the way its described in several places by google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provide is a very naive claim by a 3rd party.

A more recent (though still old) quote [from the bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=171147#c13):

> Again, since window types 'panel' and 'detached_panel' are not yet shipped outside of experimental developer builds, I'd recommend to assume they may never actually ship and avoid dependency on those window types.

Very recently, the `infobar` API that was in Dev builds for ages was scrapped. So not only we can't predict **when** it will hit stable, we can't predict **if** it will **ever** hit stable.

Comment: thank you! also I found this useful too: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/oh-ztVT6Xok